# Getting TOP N pairs of products, that customers buy commonly

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I faced such a problem of returning top N pairs of products, that customers buy in common. Let say I have following query:

```
SELECT c.CustomerKey, ProductAlternateKey
FROM 
    [AdventureWorksDW2008R2].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] FIS JOIN
    dbo.DimCustomer C ON C.CustomerKey = FIS.CustomerKey JOIN
    dbo.DimProduct P ON P.ProductKey = FIS.ProductKey

GROUP BY 
    C.CustomerKey, P.ProductAlternateKey
```

And it returns following results:

```
CustomerKey  | ProductAlternateKey| 
-------------+-----------+
0001         | A                  |
0001         | B                  |
0002         | A                  | 
0002         | B                  |
0002         | C                  |
0003         | B                  |
0003         | C                  |
0004         | A                  |
0004         | B                  |
0005         | A                  |
0005         | C                  |
```

From this query I'd like to find top 2 pairs of products that customers buy, so in my example -> (A,B) 3 occurrences and (B,C) -> 2 occurrences

Comment: And what would the answer be in this case?

Comment: I edited my question by adding answers in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a test:

```
declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int,  Description varchar(32), ProductId int, Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 1, 20),(1, 'Shoes', 2, 50),(2, 'Shirt', 1, 22),(2, 'Shoes', 2, 20),(3, 'Shirt', 1, 20),(3, 'Shoes', 2, 50),(3, 'Hat',   3, 20),(4, 'Shirt', 1, 20),(5, 'Shirt', 1, 20),(5, 'Pants', 4, 30),(6, 'Shirt', 1, 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 5, 70),(6, 'Hat', 3, 20),(7, 'Shirt', 1, 22),(7, 'Shoes', 2, 40),(7, 'Coat', 6, 80);

select
     top 2       
     I.Description,
     M.Description
from @Orders as I
inner join @Orders as C on C.ProductId = I.ProductId   and C.PersonId <> I.PersonId
inner join @Orders as M on C.PersonId = M.PersonId and C.ProductId <> M.ProductId
where 
    I.productid = 3
    and I.ProductId<>M.ProductId
group by 
    I.Description
    ,M.Description
order
    by count(2) desc
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but I'm not sure if it works as it suppose to. When I select Top 3 it returns Shoes - Shirts and Shirts - Shoes as different pairs.

Comment: I removed the top section completely and did not get what you suggested

Comment: It was because I remove condition of "productID = 3". Is it possible to  make it without fixing productID ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a RANK or DENSERANK function.  MSDN on Rank function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Example usage with self extracting SQL:

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Sean'),('Chad'),('Michael'),('Ray'),('Erik'),('Queyn');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Desciption varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shoes', 50),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Shoes', 20),(3, 'Shirt', 20),(3, 'Shoes', 50),(3, 'Hat', 20),(4, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Shirt', 20),(5, 'Pants', 30),
(6, 'Shirt', 20),(6, 'RunningShoes', 70),(7, 'Shirt', 22),(7, 'Shoes', 40),(7, 'Coat', 80);

with a as 
    (
    Select
        person
    ,   o.Desciption
    ,   o.Amount
    ,   rank() over(partition by p.personId order by Amount) as Ranking
    ,   Dense_rank() over(partition by p.personId order by Amount) as DenseRanking
    from @Person p
        join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
    )
select *
from a 
where Ranking <= 2  -- determine top 2, 3, etc.... whatever you want.
order by person, amount
```

Comment: I think this query will return most frequently purchased product rather than pair of products, that are purchased together. But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: You can change the 'partition by' section of the windowed function to cut it down further.  For instances if I had an order 'type' like red or blue shirt.  I could do over(partition by p.personid, o.type order by Amount).  Essentially the grouping is the partition by and the order by is how determine the ranking of what is first or last place.  When you want the median, or top n values; windowed functions become very powerful due to their flexibility to be used inline rather than forcing a grouping clause.  I could even do 4 or 5 more and since I do not need a grouping, it is flexible.